# jquery dataTable add new row

Tags: jquery, datatable

Hello I am trying to add new record into jquery data Table and I followed all steps from https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/AddingNewRecords

Now I can add new record into database. But unfortunately  the newly added data is not showing in the data Table without refreshing the whole page.

my front end code is as below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        $(document).ready( function () {
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "aaSorting":[], "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            }).makeEditable({
                                sAddNewRowFormId: "formAddNewRow",
                                            sAddURL: "supplier/AddSupplier.php",
                                sAddHttpMethod: "POST", 
                                            //sDeleteURL: "DeleteData.php"
                                            sAddNewRowButtonId: "btnNewRow"

                                    }); // end of data Table function

                         } ); //end of document ready function



    </script>
```

the server side page code:

```
    //AddData.php
  foreach ($_GET as $var => $value) {
  $$var =$value; 
 }
foreach ($_POST as $var => $value) {
  $$var =$value;
  include '../config.php'; 
 }

  $name = $_POST['name'] ;
  $company = $_POST['company'] ;
  $address = $_POST['address'] ;
  $phone = $_POST['phone'] ;

 $sql_add = "insert into supplier(name,company,address,phone) values('$name','$company','$address','$phone') ";
 $exe_add = mysql_db_query($sqldb,$sql_add);


  $myID = mysql_insert_id();

 $sql_sup = "select * from supplier where id = '$myID' ";
 $exe_sup = mysql_db_query($sqldb,$sql_sup);
 $sup = mysql_fetch_array($exe_sup);

 echo $sup['id'];
```

please suggest me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you first load the data, its stored in the DOM. So your new row is not in the original data. Thats why you need to reload your DOM to view the new data.

You should look into something like http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnReloadAjax